# Heroku Keeps timing out: Error waiting for network: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

My index.js file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const levels = require('discord-xp');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const mongoose = require('./database/mongoose');
const fs = require(`fs`);
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const host = '0.0.0.0';

const chalk = require('chalk');
const { Player } = require('discord-player');
const Gamedig = require('gamedig');

client.prefix = (`${process.env.PREFIX}`);
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

client.player = new Player(client);
client.config = require('./config/bot');
client.emotes = client.config.emojis;
client.filters = client.config.filters;

fs.readdirSync('./commands').forEach(dirs => {
    const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dirs}`).filter(files => files.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of commands) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${dirs}/${file}`);
        console.log(`Loading command ${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name.toLowerCase(), command);
    };
});
const player = fs.readdirSync(`./player`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const events = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of player) {
    console.log(`Loading discord-player event ${file}`);
    const event = require(`./player/${file}`);
    client.player.on(file.split(".")[0], event.bind(null, client));
};
for (const file of events) {
    console.log(`Loading discord.js event ${file}`);
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    client.on(file.split(".")[0], event.bind(null, client));
};

mongoose.init();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

My Procfile:

```
Worker: node index.js
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "icrp-bot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Made For ICRP ",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": ".test",
      "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "author": "Bombo43453#1901",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^0.21.1",
      "baseplayer": "^0.2.9",
      "chalk": "^4.1.1",
      "discord-fivem-api": "^1.0.4",
      "discord-player": "^3.4.0",
      "discord-xp": "^1.1.14",
      "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
      "ffmpeg-static": "^4.3.0",
      "gamedig": "^3.0.1",
      "log-timestamp": "^0.3.0",
      "moment": "^2.29.1",
      "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
      "mongoose": "^5.11.14",
      "node-gyp": "^8.0.0",
      "opus": "0.0.0",
      "opusscript": "0.0.8",
      "pm2": "^4.5.6",
      "python": "0.0.4",
      "rebuild": "^0.1.2"
    }
}
```

Full Error:

```
2021-04-23T17:18:33.808571+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-04-23T17:18:43.196477+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-04-23T17:18:43.846098+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-23T17:18:43.854420+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Idling
2021-04-23T17:18:43.856605+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-04-23T17:18:43.870047+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Idling because quota is exhausted
2021-04-23T17:18:50.422071+00:00 app[Worker.1]: Error waiting for network: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Info: this is a simple bot I have made for a fivem server. I tried to host it with heroku and tried to fix it. I tried adding a port const and a const host but that did not fix anything. I also think that my issue is very small and I have 200 hours left on heroku meaning that hours are not the issue. I tried changing the port to 8080 too and that did not help with anything. If you have an idea please tell me.

Comment: I don't really know what that error means, but when you create new account in heroku will probably not show up.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you have 200 hours left.
But `Idling because quota is exhausted` only shows when you **run out of free hours**.

Also you said you changed the port to 8080 but please note that **YOU CAN'T CHANGE THE PORT ON HEROKU** you get the port as env variable (Like `process.env.PORT` as you did above) and you can't change it.

If you're using worker that means you can't run a web process and the PORT is useless anyway.

About your last Error this is from Heroku support
`This is caused by kernel-level issues that can surface occasionally on the backend instances that dynos run on. Unfortunately, there is not really a work around for this issue. Scheduler dynos will crash if this happens and the job will not be executed again until its next scheduled run time. Other dyno types will typically enter a bad state and require a manual restart (you may see "App boot timeout" errors when this happens).`
Check [this](https://help.heroku.com/7CW5LBC5/why-am-i-getting-error-waiting-for-network-resource-temporarily-unavailable-errors)